# TyperError python API bot

Tags: python, api

I tried to make a simple bot API to answer the questions of the specified user, but when writing a command to the bot, a TypeError ("'in ' requires string as left operand, not int") is displayed in the python console

According to the functionality, the bot should start responding to the message of the user, which the administrator has indicated by sending the message and the command + hate [prefix]

```
import time
import vk_api
import random
import config as c
from modules import sqlite_methods as m
from threading import Thread
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=c.u_token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
vk = vk_session.get_api()


def send_msg_reply(reply_to: int, peer_id: int, message: str, attachment: str = ""):
    return vk.messages.send(**locals(), random_id=0)


def send_msg(peer_id: int, message: str, attachment: str = ""):
    return vk.messages.send(**locals(), random_id=0)


message_user_ids = []
message_users = m.get_all_message_users()
for user in message_users:
    message_user_ids.append(user[0])

photo_user_ids = []
photo_users = m.get_all_photo_users()
for user in photo_users:
    photo_user_ids.append(user[0])

settings_result = []
settings = m.get_settings(1)
for value in settings:
    settings_result.append(value)

random.shuffle(c.MESSAGE_VARIANTS)
random.shuffle(c.PHOTO_VARIANTS)


def hate():
    message_index = 0
    photo_index = 0
    while True:
        try:
            for event in longpoll.listen():
                if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

                    if event.user_id in message_user_ids:
                        if not event.from_me:
                            if message_index < len(c.MESSAGE_VARIANTS):
                                time.sleep(settings_result[1])
                                send_msg_reply(event.message_id, event.peer_id, f'{c.MESSAGE_VARIANTS[message_index]}')
                                message_index += 1
                            else:
                                message_index = 0
                                random.shuffle(c.MESSAGE_VARIANTS)
                                time.sleep(settings_result[1])
                                send_msg_reply(event.message_id, event.peer_id, f'{c.MESSAGE_VARIANTS[message_index]}')
                                message_index += 1

                    if event.user_id in photo_user_ids:
                        if not event.from_me:
                            if photo_index < len(c.PHOTO_VARIANTS):
                                time.sleep(settings_result[2])
                                send_msg_reply(event.message_id, event.peer_id, '', f'{c.PHOTO_VARIANTS[photo_index]}')
                                photo_index += 1
                            else:
                                photo_index = 0
                                random.shuffle(c.PHOTO_VARIANTS)
                                time.sleep(settings_result[2])
                                send_msg_reply(event.message_id, event.peer_id, '', f'{c.PHOTO_VARIANTS[photo_index]}')
                                photo_index += 1

        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))


def commands():
    while True:
        try:
            for event in longpoll.listen():
                if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

                    text = event.text
                    split_text = event.text.split(' ')

                    if split_text[0] in c.hate:
                        if len(split_text) == 2 and split_text[1] in c.hate_message_prefix:
                            if event.user_id in c.u_admins:
                                msg = vk.messages.getById(message_ids=event.message_id)['items'][0]
                                if 'reply_message' in msg:
                                    user = msg['reply_message']['from_id']
                                    if user != c.bot_id:
                                        if not m.is_message_user_hatelisted(user):
                                            message_user_ids.append(user)
                                            m.insert_message_hatelist(user)
                                            send_msg(event.peer_id, '✅ Пользователь добавлен в текстовый хейт лист')
                                        else:
                                            send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Пользователь уже находится в текстовом хейт листе')
                                    else:
                                        send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Невозможно добавить бота в хейт лист')
                                else:
                                    send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Пользователь не указан')
                            else:
                                choice = random.choice(c.ERRORS)
                                send_msg(event.peer_id, f'{choice}')

                        elif len(split_text) == 2 and split_text[1] in c.hate_photo_prefix:
                            if event.user_id in c.u_admins:
                                msg = vk.messages.getById(message_ids=event.message_id)['items'][0]
                                if 'reply_message' in msg:
                                    user = msg['reply_message']['from_id']
                                    if user != c.bot_id:
                                        if not m.is_photo_user_hatelisted(user):
                                            photo_user_ids.append(user)
                                            m.insert_photo_hatelist(user)
                                            send_msg(event.peer_id, '✅ Пользователь добавлен в фото хейт лист')
                                        else:
                                            send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Пользователь уже находится в фото хейт листе')
                                    else:
                                        send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Невозможно добавить бота в хейт лист')
                                else:
                                    send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Пользователь не указан')
                            else:
                                choice = random.choice(c.ERRORS)
                                send_msg(event.peer_id, f'{choice}')
                        else:
                            send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Неверный формат команды')

                    if split_text[0] in c.unhate:
                        if len(split_text) == 2 and split_text[1] in c.hate_message_prefix:
                            if event.user_id in c.u_admins:
                                msg = vk.messages.getById(message_ids=event.message_id)['items'][0]
                                if 'reply_message' in msg:
                                    user = msg['reply_message']['from_id']
                                    if m.is_message_user_hatelisted(user):
                                        message_user_ids.remove(user)
                                        m.delete_message_hatelist(user)
                                        send_msg(event.peer_id, '✅ Пользователь удален из текстового хейт листа')
                                    else:
                                        send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Пользователь отсутствует в текстовом хейт листе')
                                else:
                                    send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Пользователь не указан')
                            else:
                                choice = random.choice(c.ERRORS)
                                send_msg(event.peer_id, f'{choice}')

                        elif len(split_text) == 2 and split_text[1] in c.hate_photo_prefix:
                            if event.user_id in c.u_admins:
                                msg = vk.messages.getById(message_ids=event.message_id)['items'][0]
                                if 'reply_message' in msg:
                                    user = msg['reply_message']['from_id']
                                    if m.is_photo_user_hatelisted(user):
                                        photo_user_ids.remove(user)
                                        m.delete_photo_hatelist(user)
                                        send_msg(event.peer_id, '✅ Пользователь удален из фото хейт листа')
                                    else:
                                        send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Пользователь отсутствует в фото хейт листе')
                                else:
                                    send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Пользователь не указан')
                            else:
                                choice = random.choice(c.ERRORS)
                                send_msg(event.peer_id, f'{choice}')
                        else:
                            send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Неверный формат команды')

                    if split_text[0] in c.cooldown:
                        if len(split_text) == 3 and split_text[1] in c.hate_message_prefix and split_text[2].isnumeric():
                            if event.user_id in c.u_admins:
                                settings_result.pop(1)
                                settings_result.insert(1, int(split_text[2]))
                                m.set_message_cooldown(int(split_text[2]), 1)
                                send_msg(event.peer_id, f'✅ Задержка текста изменена на {split_text[2]} секунд')
                            else:
                                choice = random.choice(c.ERRORS)
                                send_msg(event.peer_id, f'{choice}')

                        elif len(split_text) == 3 and split_text[1] in c.hate_photo_prefix and split_text[2].isnumeric():
                            if event.user_id in c.u_admins:
                                settings_result.pop(2)
                                settings_result.insert(2, int(split_text[2]))
                                m.set_photo_cooldown(int(split_text[2]), 1)
                                send_msg(event.peer_id, f'✅ Задержка фото изменена на {split_text[2]} секунд')
                            else:
                                choice = random.choice(c.ERRORS)
                                send_msg(event.peer_id, f'{choice}')
                        else:
                            send_msg(event.peer_id, '❎ Неверный формат команды')
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=hate, args=[]).start()
    Thread(target=commands, args=[]).start()
```